# PayPal API - cancel_url gives only token?

Tags: api, paypal

Is it possible to get the Payer ID?

The  `return_url` provides Payer ID, amount etc .. while the `cancel_url` gives only token.

Answer (score 0):

There was no payment, so no payer, so no payer ID. There was no transaction, so no transaction ID. No money was paid, so no amount.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Paypal-PHP-SDK is not possible at this moment, the unique solution for now is save the token when you create the payment. In DEV-MASTER branch they have added a new method called "getToken()" to Payment class, so you will get the token easily when you create a payment. You can track the issue using the next URL [Paypal-PHP-SDK issue 832](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/832)

```
$payment->create($apiContext);
$token = $payment->getToken();
```

PS: Remember, this method "getToken()" is only available in DEV-MASTER for now.